# Excel special symbols in formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, special-characters, excel-2013, metatrader4

Folks,

I am trying to run DDE ( with MetaTrader Terminal 4 platform ) from Excel info using a defined syntax of **`'= MT4|ASK!USDCHF'`** and it works fine.

However, when I try to use it for a **`#GOOG`** symbol or for a **`^Coffee`**, Excel returns it as a formula being corrupt.

The reason for it, obviously is that '`#`' or '`^`' after **`ASK!`** doesn't get recognised as a normal string value.

How do I embed such symbols? ASCII didn't help either since it works on the output value, not on the input value.

Comment: Perhaps try putting single quotes around it? E.g. `= ASK!'#GOOG'`?

Comment: OMG. Just omg. I tried it before - it didnt work, not it did....but! How come when I create a new 2013 excel spreadsheet it gives me an error if I use the above formula, but using a DDE-Sample (GitHub has it) - the exact same formula works fine...difference in defining the formula bar?! That's why when I tried single quotation marks - it didn't work!

Comment: OKAY! Found the problem: when one uses pre 2013 Excel - you don't have to do single quotation marks ' ' around the MT4, BUT in 2013 and newer the exclusion of them makes excel go nuts!